# Is there any tool/package to automatically add papers from their arxiv IDs?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm a physics undergrad, and i am writing a report which requires citing papers, and so i was wondering if there exists any package that automatically adds citations from their arxiv/PRL/etc id?

Comment: Depending on your editor, you could maybe add a macro to interact with some parser like for example https://arxiv2bibtex.org/

Comment: http://inspirehep.net/info/hep/tools/bibliography_generate

Comment: If you use [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) you can try [org-ref](https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref) which have a library which add bibtex entries from arxiv.org

Comment: Thank you for your helpful suggestions. Will check them out for sure

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to retrieve a bib entry based on the arXiv number

- [arxiv2bibtex.org](http://arxiv2bibtex.org/) is a website where you can enter the arXiv identifier and it will generate the `.bib` entry. It will even warn you if a paper is still unpublished and you should enter the journal information once it is available.
- You can also retrieve the information from the [NASA ADS data base](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/). You can find a direct link in the sidebar of the arXiv page

[image]

Once on the ADS page, you can download the `.bib` entry

[image]

- ... - there are many more automatic data bases

For all of them: Don't blindly trust them and have a look at [Software-generated bibliographic entries: common errors and other mistakes to check before use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386053/software-generated-bibliographic-entries-common-errors-and-other-mistakes-to-ch)

Comment: Sorry, for messing with the edits ...

Comment: @moewe Don't worry. I'll sort it out in a minute.

Comment: @moewe I posted the unfinished answer fast, because there where already several close votes.

Comment: @moewe I tried to redo all your edits - could you please check if I missed something?

Comment: Looks good. Thank you. And sorry for jumping in too quickly.